# How to fix symbols of layers when I copy .mxd to another pc?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, mxd, copy

I've created a personal geodatabase with feature classes and I specified symbols for them in an mxd project. I activated "store relative pathnames to data sources" in the Map Document Properties. When I sent the project and database to another computer, the symbols of feature classes were changed. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: if you send the MXD and personal geo-database to another computer the symbols shouldn't change at all.  can you please give a screenshot example of what has happened?

Comment: [link](http://snag.gy/eG3FM.jpg), first image is original project, bottom image is copied project. @Midavalo

Comment: The bottom image has filename 'untitled' which leads me to think the user hasn't opened the existing MXD on the second computer.  Symbology is stored in the MXD or in layer files, not in the geodatabase.

Comment: Problem was that my schoolmate doesn't open it in original project. :-D everything is o.k.  @Midavalo

Comment: I have added as answer.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom image has filename 'untitled' which leads me to think the user hasn't opened the existing MXD on the second computer.

Symbology is stored in the MXD or in layer files, not in the geodatabase.

[image]